# Stop 'bouncing' input from float sensor

Tags: capacitor, solenoid, delay

I'm trying to resolve an electro-mechanical issue to do with a water fill solenoid, that is triggered by a float valve. The problem is as the water approaches full, the float bounces causing the solenoid to rapidly switch on and off. Not great on solenoid or the water pipework that gets hammered.

Instead of adding expensive delay off timers, I was hoping to add a capacitor to the simple circuit to delay the closing of the solenoid. 1 second delay would be great, 3 or more would be better! The system runs on 24 Vdc, the relay controlling the solenoid draws around 100 mA.

Any help with sizing the right capacitor or if there is a better way would be much appreciated.

Comment: You can't add some dampening to the float's lever?

Answer (score 0):

Position the float sensor so that the incoming flow presses down on it.

Comment: Unfortunately the inlet is nowhere near the float. Its a 5000lt stainless tank. There's also 3 of them I need to solve the solution for.

Comment: perhaps add magnets to make the float stick in the down position so that it pops to the up when there's a higher fluid level.

Comment: usually we just use an heavier float. The capacitor idea is mostly correct but impratical due the required values

Answer (score 0):

Use two float switches combined with a relay. The lower switch turns the solenoid ON, while the upper switch turns it OFF. So you have a hysteresis.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fVXUp2.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>